# How do I alter the value of a field?

Tags: 7, views

I am struggling with changing the URL of my field in a view.
I am using the following code.

```
function mymodule_views_pre_render(&$view) {
 $view->field['title']->options['alter']['text'] = 'My custom text';
 $view->field['title']->options['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;
 $view->field['title']->options['alter']['make_link'] = TRUE;
 $view->field['title']->options['alter']['path'] = "http://url.com";
}
```

The title changes, but the link doesn't.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try custom field template for this?

Comment: Custom field template? Could you please provide more detail on this?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/modules/views/theming-a-single-field-in-a-views-3-template

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to use matching quotation marks in the second line. Your current code has this: 'My custom text"

It should have this: 'My custom text'

That is, you have a single quotation mark to open the string, but a double quotation mark to close it. That's causing the rest of your block to be quoted. Change the double quotation mark to a single quotation mark.